# Question on manipulating an array to add zeros every nth, n-1th, n-2th

Tags: python

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
array([  9.30120000e+04,   5.10000000e+02,   9.47120000e+04,
     1.40650000e+04,   7.02300000e+04,   1.19980000e+04,
     7.04770000e+04,   1.50690000e+04,   1.64640000e+04,
     7.83000000e+02,   7.05700000e+03,   4.34000000e+02,
     7.18200000e+03,   4.32900000e+03,   7.78200000e+03,
     5.37300000e+03,   8.89500000e+03,   7.29000000e+02,
     1.71000000e+02,   7.20000000e+02,   3.82000000e+02,
     6.86000000e+02,   6.23000000e+02,   4.70000000e+02,
     8.86000000e+02,   4.07000000e+02,   2.81000000e+02,
     1.71000000e+02,   5.21000000e+02,   5.53000000e+02,
     6.40000000e+01,   3.26000000e+02,   4.68000000e+02,
     4.10000000e+02,   4.63000000e+02,   3.63000000e+02,
     2.60000000e+01,   4.11000000e+02,   2.75000000e+02,
     9.80000000e+01,   2.24000000e+02,   3.16000000e+02,
     1.10000000e+02,   2.79000000e+02,   4.90000000e+02])
```

However, I want to make it look something like this:

```
array([[  9.30120000e+04,   5.10000000e+02,   9.47120000e+04,
      1.40650000e+04,   7.02300000e+04,   1.19980000e+04,
      7.04770000e+04,   1.50690000e+04,   1.64640000e+04],
   [  7.83000000e+02,   7.05700000e+03,   4.34000000e+02,
      7.18200000e+03,   4.32900000e+03,   7.78200000e+03,
      5.37300000e+03,   8.89500000e+03,   **0.00000000e+00**],
   [  7.29000000e+02,   1.71000000e+02,   7.20000000e+02,
      3.82000000e+02,   6.86000000e+02,   6.23000000e+02,
      4.70000000e+02,   **0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00**],
   [  8.86000000e+02,   4.07000000e+02,   2.81000000e+02,
      1.71000000e+02,   5.21000000e+02,   5.53000000e+02,
      **0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00**],
   [  6.40000000e+01,   3.26000000e+02,   4.68000000e+02,
      4.10000000e+02,   4.63000000e+02,   **0.00000000e+00**,
      **0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00**],
   [  3.63000000e+02,   2.60000000e+01,   4.11000000e+02,
      2.75000000e+02,   **0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00**,
      **0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00**],
   [  9.80000000e+01,   2.24000000e+02,   3.16000000e+02,
      **0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00**],
   [  1.10000000e+02,   2.79000000e+02,   **0.00000000e+00**,
      **0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00**],
   [  4.90000000e+02,   **0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00**,
      **0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
      0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00**]])
```

That is, for the first N = 9 elements, create a separate tuple, for the next N-1 = 8 elements add a 0 and create another tuple of dimension 9, for the next N-2 elements add two 0's and create another tuple of dimension 9, and so on.

I tried using the Insert function and manipulating the array but no success. Has anyone stumbled with a similar problem before that could share some code?

Comment: use numpy for such kind of numerical computations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `input_arr` is you array. You could build it in a loop:

```
output_arr = []
zeroes = 0
idx = 0
n = len(input_arr)
while idx < n:
    end_idx = min(idx + 9, n)
    nine_tuple = input_arr[idx:end_idx] #get the nine tuple
    for i in range(zeroes + 1):
        nine_tuple[8-i] = 0 #make the last few elements 0
    idx = end_idx
    zeroes = (zeroes + 1) % 9 #mod to make sure you dont go out of range
    output_arr.append(nine_tuple)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! It was actually close to what I was looking for. I made the modifications below and the result is what I wanted.